# Многоязычность и Smarty

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html, smarty, css

**Доброго времени суток!**

Интересует возможность красивой и эффективной реализации поддержки мультиязычности с использованием PHP шаблонизатора Smarty версии 3.

Мне в голову приходит только 3 идеи:

1. Замены всех надписей на константы или глобальные переменные (определенные в конф. файлах). Таким образом появиться возможность создания что-то типа language pack. Главными недостатками есть значительное понижение производительности и захламление шаблона переменными.
2. Формирование для каждого языка отдельного файла шаблона - "*.tpl". То есть для страницы "home" с поддержкой 4-х языков нуна будет писать соответственно четыре идентичных по разметке шаблона. Данное решение убивает напрочь удобство редактирования шаблонов.
3. Погрузка language pack и перевод текста страницы средствами javascript. Это вообще извращение, как по мне.

Прошу помочь с поиском альтернативных решений. Пример шаблона: [demo](http://uzumaxy.tk/test/) | [source](http://uzumaxy.tk/test/source/sb_admin.7z) Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не пожалею 1024 балла за действительно хорошую идею =) Ф-я "наградить" ведь такое позволяет?

Comment: > Замены всех надписей на константы или глобальные переменные (определенные в конф. файлах)

Обычно примерно так и локализуют.

Comment: Что если использовать второй вариант? Но редактировать только один, оригинальный шаблон (для языка по-умолчанию), а остальные генерировать скриптом?

Необходимо сформировать шаблон страницы home с локализациями en, ru, ua, jp:

 1. Создать файл "home-en.tpl"
 2. Создать таблицу переводов, где фрагментам тексту из "home-en.tpl" соответствуют отображения на нужных языках
 3. Сгенерировать файлы "home-ru.tpl", "home-ua.tpl", "home-jp.tpl"

Или в этого способа есть какие-то критические недочеты, которые Я пропустил?

Comment: А вот [этот][1] вариант сильно будет бить по продуктивности?

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476558/making-smarty-supporting-multiple-languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://habrahabr.ru/post/115300/

Answer (score 1):

1 вариант самый оптимальный. При подключении кеширования производительность повыситься.
2 вариант не стоит использовать, так как при каждом изменении дизайна придётся ковырять шаблон для каждого языка, а это время и силы. К тому же место на хосте это все шаблоны * на количество языков.
3 вариант вообще не вариант. Несмотря на развитие технологий, всё ещё удивляюсь проглядывая статистику посещений своих сайтов когда виже IE5. Так же есть уникалы которые блокируют флеш и выполнение JS.

Comment: Про первый вариант.
Да, шаблон не будет компилироваться при каждом вызове, но все-равно придется обрабатывать огромное количество переменных. 
И сами шаблоны нехило так засорятся вставками переменных Smarty.

Comment: Шаблоны в размере не раздуются. Используйте сокращённые наименования.
Также можно использовать групповые индексы. Формата {$smarty.prodName}  {$smarty.prodCountry} {$smarty.catName}  - где prod и cat группы констант.
И как говорил стервятник в старом мультике:"Лучше день потерять, потом за пять минут долететь". Один раз скомпилирует кеш, а дальше проще будет.

Answer (score 1):

первый вариант, только немного переделываем..

```
{i18n def="Greetings"}

function i18n()
{
    // из сессии / таблици пользовательских настроек и т.д.. достаём язык, в котором нужно показывать.
    // далее загружаем и кешируем в памяти все переводы по этому языку. Например так:
    static $translate;
    if (!isset($translate[$lang])) {
        $translate[$lang] = unserialize(file_get_contents(TRANSLATE_FILES.'/'.$lang.'.pack'));
    }
    // в этом файле будет значение => перевод, достаем параметр def,
    // в данном случае это равнозначно: $translate['Greetings']
}
```

Естественно, нужно проверять есть ли файл: TRANSLATE_FILES.'/'.$lang.'.pack'
Если нету, то загружать из базы и сохранять данные в файл.

Хранить это можно в таблице, например такой вот структуры:

id | lang | t_key | t_value | url

t_key рекомендую делать регистрозависимым. т.е utf8_bin

если в $translate нету нужного нам ключа: вставляем его в таблицу со значением, например: '['.$params['def'].']', т.е если мы встречаем фразу в квадратных скобка, скорее всего это не переведенный вариант, можно также добавить в таблицу флаг о непереведенности. А также удаляем файл кеша.

Параметр url нужен для отладки, что бы понять на какой странице был отображен перевод.

Преимущества такого способа очевидны:
 * автовставка переводов
 * перевод хранятся в базе, можно через админку их переводить (естсетвенно, после окончания перевода нужно удалять кеш файл)
 * не нужно переписывать код, для добавления языка.
 * Придумайте чтото сами :)